# JOscarLib - how to use?

Tags: java, icq

How to use JOscarLib? I have to fix unworkable code with this lib, but I don't know, why I have some errors.
I do this:

```
connection = new OscarConnection(auth.getHost(), auth.getPort(), auth.getUsername(), auth.getPassword());
```

But get this:

```
OscarLib.Core.JarClassLoader cacheClasses
WARNING: Warning : No jar file found. Packet unmarshalling won't be possible. Please verify your classpath
... JOscarLib.Core.OscarPacketAnalyser handleService
INFO: Received 1 - 3
... JOscarLib.Core.OscarPacketAnalyser handleService
INFO: Received 1 - 21
```

After this connection.isLogged == false with true username/password and host=login.icq.com and port=5190/443

By the way, does this library works today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used icqlib library and it worked.